# How to overcome Access Page Locks

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an Microsoft Access application in which the main page is a form bound to the main table in the database (holding company information).  This is a linked table to a SQL Server backend. There are approximately 40000 records in the database and multiple users.

Normally the form is opened without any filters.

There is a drop down list to find a specific company - which then re-opens the form with a where condition.  Users tend to untoggle the filter button when they have finished working with the specific company.

I have discovered that Access takes out a shared Page Lock on the SQL Server table when no filter is in place.  This can cause a problem when someone else is trying to update or insert a new record into the company table (they time out waiting for the shared lock to be released). Access removes the page lock as soon as any filtering takes place

I have also discovered that if I use the navigation button at the bottom of the form to go to the last record the page lock is released.

Is there anyway I can programatically cause access to release this lock - I tried going to the last record in the on_ApplyFilter event - but I presume (since you can cancel it) that this occurs before the filter is removed, not after.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a query and use the query behind your form.  All you need to do is select * from the table, but add one piece of code:

```
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM MyTable with (NoLock);"

Me.RecordSource = sSQL
```

Comment: I already solved the problem related to the specific issue - see the answer I just posted, so I haven't actually checked your answer but I still think I need locks in case there is a real case of someone editing the record and causing a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered how to make this work.  My speculation about the On_ApplyFilter being too early was correct, but you can use a timer.

On the on_ApplyFilter event I just set Me.TimerInterval = 100 and do the same on Form Load.

The in the timer event I just do

```
Me.TimerInterval = 0
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acLast
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acFirst
```

This solves the problem - doesn't seem to take any time to traverse the 40000 records and leaves the SQL Server Database free of Locks when it completes