# Access Listbox query preventing SQL Server Update Query

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures, listbox

I'm developing an Access application and a SQL Server backend simultaneously. I have a Form with a listbox which, when a record is double clicked, opens an unbound form and loads data into it based on the record selected.  When changes are made in this second form, a button initiates a pass through query that executes a stored procedure updating the details of the record in the base table in SQL Server.

Here's the thing. As long as Form1 (with the listbox) is open, the stored procedure times out without running.  If I close that form, it takes less than a second. It behaves this way when run from Access, when run from management studio, and when run in management studio as a query with hard values (not a sproc with parameters).

The row source for the listbox is a linked table that references a View in SQL Server. The query within the view is a recursive common table expression of two different tables, one of which is the table being edited by the sproc.  I've set the view to read only.  Is there another setting that I can do to help here?

Here's the stored procedure:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSalesPlanUpdate]
    @Salesyear numeric(4,0),
    @ItemNumber varchar(20),
    @Baseline int,
    @Speculation int,
    @Comments varchar(max)
AS
declare @SY numeric(4,0),
        @ItN varchar (20),
        @BL int,
        @SPL int,
        @CmT varchar(max)
set @SY = @Salesyear
set @ItN = @ItemNumber
set @BL = @Baseline
set @SPL = @Speculation
set @CmT = @Comments

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


   update SalesPlan
   set Baseline = @BL
        ,Speculation = @SPL
        ,DateModified = getdate()
        ,Comments = @CmT
    where SalesYear = @SY and ItemNumber = @ItN
END
```

I used both parameters and local variables because at first I was thinking it might be about parameter sniffing.

Here's the view the listbox is queried from:

```
view [dbo].[vwSalesPlan] as 
with cte 
as
(
select Item, year(getdate()) as SY
from vwItemsAndLiners il

union all

select ial.Item, 
       (cte.SY + 1)
From vwItemsAndLiners ial join cte on ial.Item  = cte.Item
Where SY < (year(getdate())+ial.YearsFromProp)
)

select sp.ItemNumber, ial.Variety, ial.Size, ial.PerTray, sp.SalesYear, sp.SalesYear - ial.YearsFromProp as PropYear, 
       sp.SalesYear - ial.YearsFromProduction as ProductionYear, 
       sp.Baseline, sp.Speculation, 
       CEILING((CAST(SP.BASELINE AS NUMERIC (12,2)) + CAST(SP.SPECULATION AS numeric(12,2)))/IAL.PerTray)*IAL.PerTray as Total , 
       sp.DateModified, ial.Segment ,'Entered' as [Status], sp.Comments
From SalesPlan sp inner join vwItemsAndLiners ial on sp.ItemNumber = ial.Item
Where ial.status = 'Sell'


union 

select cte.Item, ial.Variety, ial.Size, ial.PerTray, SY, cte.sy - ial.YearsFromProp as PropYear, 
        cte.SY - ial.YearsFromProduction as ProductionYear,'', '', 0, null, ial.Segment , 'Not Entered', null
from cte inner join vwItemsAndLiners ial on cte.Item = ial.Item
where cte.Item not in (select ItemNumber from SalesPlan where salesplan.SalesYear = CTE.SY) and ial.Status = 'Sell'

with check option
```

Table being updated: SalesPlan

View that the listbox is queried from: vwSalesPlan

I realize that there's a lot of stuff here.  Really, I'm just hoping this generates some ideas of why a form being open would lock the original table from an update query. Thanks!

Comment: Access is really bad for this because it holds open locks. Not sure there is much you can do

Comment: So in SSMS I ran the query
`select * from sys.dm_exec_requests er cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text (sql_handle)`
when the listbox form is open I return 2 session IDs one with ASYNC_NETWORK_IO wait type. If I scroll to the bottom of the listbox forcing access to read all the data then run the above script again, that session ID disappears even while the listbox form is open.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535124/how-to-overcome-access-page-locks

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

- Indexing the views in SQL Server that provide the rowsource for the listbox, but because they contain CTE's they cannot be indexed.
- lstbox.recordset.movefirst then lstbox.recordset.movelast to force access to read the entire list, but whenever the list was filtered or requeried it would throw an error saying the recordset object had changed and the movefirst command was invalid.

So I wrote this sub:

```
Private Sub readtheData()
Dim i As Integer

i = Me.lstSalesPlan.ListCount

End Sub
```

Simply forcing it to count the records every time the form was loaded or the query behind the listbox was filtered forced access to release the lock.  Hope this helps somebody down the road!